# Eclipse Virtual TableViewer filtering and Sorting?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

In a RCP application, I am using a TableViewer with LazyContentProvider with SWT.VIRTUAL Flag to dispaly a large data from database. This is working fine.

But we want to filter in TableViewer and its not working.

Anybody can help me how to make virtual TableViewer with filtering and sorting...